# Реализация "кастомного" текста в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Задался таким вопросом: как сделать свою систему текста как в Unity. Вероятно всего спросите: зачем? Или уже что-то подобное есть. Я отвечу, да. Есть TextMeshPro и возможно другие. Но мне очень сильно он не подходит. Как минимум из-за того, что в нем много лишнего. Хотелось бы сделать простейшие инициализации внутри текста команды. Атрибуты другими словами. Ссылки. Добавление спрайтов, через коды. К примеру

Всем привет, друзья `<smilespr=код смайлика>`
А в окне Game в чате было так: Всем привет, друзья 
Нужны такие команды как: 
`<color=#000000></color>` - Чтобы поменять цвет
 `<br>` - Чтобы сделать отступ
 `<href="Имя метода">Мечь</href>` - Чтобы в чат можно было показывать вещи, и нажимать на них, будто это ссылка
 `<menter exstart=#000f00 exend=#000000></menter>` - Когда наводишь на текст, можно было управлять цветом текста и background текста. В определенной области.

И простые настройки шрифта, размер и т.д. Без лишних функций.
Может есть где-нибудь какие уроки, документация хоть что-нибудь. Может, уже кто-то писал и у вас есть ссылка на Git. Я был бы рад. Я даже начать не могу, потому что не знаю с чего даже начать... Спасибо большое.

Comment: я бы начал с изучения родного Text в юнити https://github.com/liuqiaosz/Unity/blob/master/UGUI%E6%BA%90%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Text.cs

Comment: Так, спасибо. Допустим я уже могу сделать шаблон. Что уже и начал. Но ответ на основной вопрос так нет. Как мне сделать внутренний компилятор. Чтобы можно было вставлять аргументы.

Comment: Вообще не знаю что такое внутренний компилятор. Судя по задаче тебе необходимо просто заменять определенный текст из списка на картинку или другой текст через банальный риплейс и вставку текствого смайла. Если там будет много текста - то необходимо будет писать собственный рендер который будет расчитывать положение картинок которые необходимо вславлять и рендерить автоматом подставляя изображение. То есть буквально заниматься отрисовкой каждого отдельного элемента. А что такое "внутренний компилятор" я не знаю